# Magento Connect Manager 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, ce-1.9.1.0, 404, magento-connect-manager

Before you mark this thread as duplicate please read the following:

I'm having a hard time getting to **Connect manager**
I tried all possible solutions from **similar threads** like:

- Changing folder and file permissions for downloader directory(755 for dir,644 for file)
- flushing cache(although i didn't delete it, just did the "Clear magento cache
- from admin panel")
- i did permission reset for directories so all permissions are having default values.
- tried to access manager directly(mysite.com/downloader/index.php)

I'm getting desperate... I hope there is someone to help me solve this problem.

Magento ver is 1.9.1.0

Comment: Can you have a look at the log files and share them here? I also would like to see the network and console tab within your chrome developer console.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest for my problem. Console is empty so i'll skip that part.
Exception log -  https://ufile.io/wg93q

Comment: https://ibb.co/mwptL6 - network tab

Comment: Could you also provide the PHP and web server error logs, please?

Comment: I've only found this one https://ufile.io/rzpbd , it's location was in var/logs which is child folder of public_html. It's a linux based server, and there is a folder log which only shows ip address activity, nothing else, also it's a shared hosting...

Answer (score 1):

With the information you gave me and those I found during my research, your problem should be solved by following the steps I provide below:

- Check file permissions in the `downloader` directory.

  - `chmod -R 755 downloader/ && chmod 644 downloader/index.php`
- Clear your cache.

  - `rm -Rf var/cache/*`
- Check the state of the module.

  - The module must not be disabled. To check that, go into `app/etc/modules`
- Make sure the file `app/code/core/Mage/Connect` is available.
- If you still not be able to access the connect manager, try to access it directly via `example.com/downloader/index.php`.

Comment: Already tried all of that, nothing changes... Permissions are ok, cache is cleared. Mage_Connect.xml is set as true, app/code/core/Mage/Connect is available, direct access doesn't help. it still says 404 Not Found. :(

Comment: ufff, hard one here... What about the webserver error logs?

Comment: I've found solution and set it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hooorayy, i've found the answer.Uploading downloader folder from another installation fixed this problem. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: This is not a solution. Now you don't know what caused the problem in the first place...